# Extract field value from mongodb BasicDBobject

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

I am developing simple web application to learn jsp, mongodb, html. I have created an simple registration form in jsp which takes Name, Address and MobileNo information from user and insert it into mongodb, Now I want to retrieve this stored data and put value of every field in individual string variable.

Ex:

> Name: varun;
>  Address: Nagpur;
>  MobileNo: 1234567890

Above data is stored in mongodb as:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5259bacea6f8b1c4cd3431d3"), 
"Name" : "varun", 
"Address" : "nagpur", 
"MobileNumber" : "1234567890" 
}
```

Retrieved in jsp as follows:

```
MongoClient mongoC = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("Localhost",27017));
DB database = mongoC.getDB("dbfrnzout");
DBCollection collec1 = database.getCollection("coll"); 
DBObject dock= collec1.findOne();
out.println(dock);
```

This code print one record as json document and I want to store value associated with every

field in individual string variable, something like this:

`String s1 = varun` ie. value of field Name

Need some guidance.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DBObject implements the Map<String, Object> interface so you should be able to do something like:

```
String name = (String) dock.get( "Name" );
String address = (String) dock.get( "Address" );
String mobileNumber = (String) dock.get( "MobileNumber" );
```

Be careful with the casts and make sure you are certain of the type and existence of each field.  For numeric values I strongly recommend casting to a `Number` instead of `Integer` since MongoDB will re-cast values to a `Long` or `Double` at the weirdest times.

HTH, Rob.

Edit: If you are iterating over the results of a query you will have to inspect each document as it is returned from the iterator

```
DBCollection collec1 = database.getCollection("coll"); 
for( DBObject dock : collec1.find() ) {
    String name = (String) dock.get( "Name" );
    String address = (String) dock.get( "Address" );
    String mobileNumber = (String) dock.get( "MobileNumber" );

    // Do Something...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, Need further help. I am using "find()" method hence I have to use DBCursor instead of DBObject hence I cant use dock.get().. Is their any alternative..

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to get an object from a cursor

while (cursor.hasNext())
    dbObject o = cursor.next()